# How to collect X type objects from a stream, that contain only some fields of the same X type object, without using an auxiliary collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

An example:

*This permits to extract one field*

```
Collection<X> base=...;
List<?> c=base.stream().map(->i.getField()).distinct.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

*This requires an auxiliary collection*

```
Collection<X> fromBase; //empty collection
Collection<X> base=...;
List<?> c=base.stream().forEach(i->{
    X k=...; //create object X with some fields
    fromBase.add(k);
});
```

There is a way to extract more fields, like with .map(), directly ?

*Basic example:*

```
List<X> lst;

private void collectDistinctItems(){
    lst = new ArrayList<>();
    getSomeItems().stream().forEach(i->{  //Collection<X>
        X tmp=new X();
        tmp.setField1(i.getField1());  //copy some fields
        tmp.setField2(i.getField2());
        tmp.setField3(i.getField3());
        ...

        if(!lst.contains(tmp)) lst.add(tmp); //add new X item to X type list
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step would be to use a collector:

```
lst = getSomeItems().stream().map(i->{  //Collection<X>
      X tmp=new X();
      tmp.setField1(i.getField1());  //copy some fields
      tmp.setField2(i.getField2());
      tmp.setField3(i.getField3());
      return tmp; })
    .distinct()
    .collect(toList());
```

You could also extract the copy into a separate method:

```
private static X copy(X original) {
    X tmp=new X();
    tmp.setField1(i.getField1());  //copy some fields
    tmp.setField2(i.getField2());
    tmp.setField3(i.getField3());
    return tmp;
}
```

and use a method reference:

```
lst = getSomeItems().stream()
    .map(MyClass::copy)
    .distinct()
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: There is a way to use .map() like .map(i->i.getField1(), i.getField2()...),
to extract directly necessary fields ?

Comment: Actually, there *are* ways to extract multiple fields but the right way depends on what you want to do with these values. Since the only thing, you gave us, is that you want to create an instance of `X` assylias’ answer is the right thing unless you give `X` an appropriate constructor. Then the solution is as simple as `.map(i -> new X(i.getField1(), i.getField2(),...))`.

Comment: @Holger Indeed. That or fluent setters: `new X().setField1(i.getField1()).setField2(i.getField2());`

Comment: **Confirmed as accepted**
`List<X> lst = getItems().stream().map(X::refactor).distinct()
.collect(Collectors.toList());`